# Can you use AND in an IF - to check two conditions - python

Tags: python

I am trying to search by two criteria matches or word starts in an input:

```
sentence=input("What is wrong with your device?\n") # variable arrays
screenissues=["scre","displ","moni","blan"]
wifiissues=["wif","connect","signal","3g","4g"]
waterdamage=["wet","damp","rain","water","soak"]
phone=["phon","samsun","calls","mobi","mob"]

for word in sentence.split(): #splits
    if (word.startswith(tuple(screenissues)) and word.startswith(tuple(phone))): #trys to serach for two criteria at once - or works...
        print( word)
        print("you have an issue with your PHONE screen, please call us")
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't use a `tuple` to check all the words - look into `any` builtin.

Comment: And you aren't comparing different words but the same word each loop - which will always be false.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to scan through all the words in the sentence before making your decision. That means the `if` statement must be after the `for` loop, not in it:

```
# Key = issue type, values = keywords
issues_types = {
    'screen': ("scre","displ","moni","blan"),
    'wifi': ("wif","connect","signal","3g","4g"),
    'water damage': ("wet","damp","rain","water","soak"),
    'phone': ("phon","samsun","calls","mobi","mob"),
}
sentence = input("What is wrong with your device?\n") # variable arrays

issues = set()
for word in sentence.split():
    for issue, keywords in issues_types.items():
        if word.lower().startswith(keywords):
            issues.add(issue)

print('It looks like you have issues with', ', '.join(issues))

# Use the set operator <= (subset) to test
if {'phone', 'screen'} <= issues:
    print('You have an issue with your PHONE screen, please call us')
```

Here are a couple of sample sessions:

```
What is wrong with your device?
my Samsung shows a blank screen
It looks like you have issues with phone, screen
You have an issue with your PHONE screen, please call us

What is wrong with your device?
My phone is soak
It looks like you have issues with phone, water damage
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "any" to make a simple decision:

```
if any(w.lower().startswith(s) for s in screenissues for w in sentence.split() ) and  \
    any(w.lower().startswith(p) for p in phone for w in sentence.split() ): #trys to serach for two criteria at once - or works...
    print ("you have an issue with your PHONE screen, please call us")
```

Sample session:

```
What is wrong with your device?
I have an issue with my SAMSUNG display when making calls!
you have an issue with your PHONE screen, please call us
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, both great.